# SES international email encoding

Tags: email, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using SES to a international email id: Dörte@gmail.com

As per SES we have to mime encode local part of the address ie Dörte

The conversion value looks this:  =?US-ASCII?Q?D=FFrte?=@gmail.com

But AWS is literally considering this as a non-converted email id.

I tried converting normal email such as myname@gmail.com into  =?US-ASCII?Q?myname?=@gmail.com & yet it failed to sent an email.

Please help in solving this critical issue

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error which you get if you try to send it to this email ID?

Comment: @rmagon issue is resolved using puny code.